# How to make my code more efficient using cython?

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I have written the following code in Python.
If I use this code, it takes 1 min 20sec:

```
def calc_cy(searchX,searchY,searchZ,dx,dz,r_vector,p_true,a_factor,sim):

calc1 = np.full((len(searchX),len(searchY),len(searchZ)),np.nan)
z_t = np.abs(np.ceil(r_vector[:,2]/dz).squeeze())

for ix in searchX:
    for iy in searchY:
        for iz in searchZ:
            dt=[]
            ir = (np.floor((((ix-r_vector[:,0])**2+(iy-r_vector[:,1])**2))**0.5)) 
            for ip in range(p_true.size):
                dt.append(sim[int(iz)][int(ir[ip]),int(z_t[ip])])

            dt_sim = dt-min(dt)
            dt_true=p_true-min(p_true[0])
            calc1[int(ix),int(iy),int(iz)]=np.linalg.norm(a_factor*(dt_sim-dt_true))
return calc1
```

If I use this code with Cython, it takes 1 min 5sec:

setup code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

setup(ext_modules = cythonize("calc_cy.pyx"), include_dirs = [numpy.get_include()])
```

The code using Cython:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
import math

DTYPE = np.double
ctypedef np.double_t DTYPE_t

def calc_cy(np.ndarray [DTYPE_t,ndim = 3] sim,np.ndarray [DTYPE_t,ndim = 1] searchX,np.ndarray [DTYPE_t,ndim = 1] searchY,np.ndarray [DTYPE_t,ndim = 1] searchZ,np.ndarray [DTYPE_t,ndim = 2] r_vector,np.ndarray [DTYPE_t,ndim = 1] p_true,np.ndarray [DTYPE_t,ndim = 1] a_factor):

    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t,ndim = 3] calc1 = np.zeros((len(searchX),len(searchY),len(searchZ)),dtype = DTYPE)
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t,ndim = 1] dt2 = np.zeros(len(p_true),dtype = DTYPE)
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t,ndim = 1] dt_sim = np.zeros(len(dt2),dtype = DTYPE)
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t,ndim = 1] dt_picks = np.zeros(len(p_true),dtype = DTYPE)

    cdef int ir
    cdef int k
    cdef int m

    for ix in range(len(searchX)):
        for iy in range(len(searchY)):
            for iz in range(len(searchZ)):
                for ip in range(len(p_true)):
                    ir= int(np.floor((((searchX[ix]-r_vector[ip,0])**2+(searchY[iy]-r_vector[ip,1])**2))**0.5))
                    k = int(searchZ[iz])
                    m = int(math.fabs(math.ceil(r_vector[ip,2])))
                    dt2[int(ip)] = sim[k,ir,m]
                dt_sim = dt2- min(dt2)
                dt_true = p_true - min(p_true)
                calc1[ix,iy,iz] = np.linalg.norm(a_factor*(dt_sim-dt_true))
    return calc1
```

How can I improve my code and doing it more efficient?
Thanks!

Comment: the time spent in numpy routines is probably the problem. Compiling the rest isn't going to make a difference. You have 4 imbricated loops too... You could drop the indexes btw. Iterate directly on the elements instead of the indices: `for ix in range(len(searchX)):` => `for x in searchX` and use `x` instead of `searchX[ix]`, that saves an list access.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre In Cython (as opposed to Python) it's usually better to index than iterate directly. Agree with the rest of what you wrote

Comment: @DavidW yes, probably true for the inner loop variable (and OP is probably aware of that fact since the python version doesn"t use that anti pattern). But not for the ix/iy variables that doesn't change in the inner loops. But after that C optimizer can detect that and make wonders.

Comment: _How can I improve my code and doing it more efficient?_ Benchmark it, profile it. We can't do that, since we are lacking code/data to run the program. There are also no explanations of the program's functioning, which makes things more difficult. Please see: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, the value of `ir` doesn't depend on `iz`, so you could move it outside of the `iz` loop.
The value of `dt_true` only depends on `p_true`, so it only needs to be calculated *once*.
These combined would eliminate unneeded recalculations, speeding up the code. (This is called [loop-invariant code motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion).)

Futhermore you could convert the calculation of `dt` to a list comprehension. That should speed up the Python version. Not sure if it would help the Cython version, though.

That would make the code look like this:

```
def calc_cy(searchX,searchY,searchZ,dx,dz,r_vector,p_true,a_factor,sim):
    calc1 = np.full((len(searchX),len(searchY),len(searchZ)),np.nan)
    z_t = np.abs(np.ceil(r_vector[:,2]/dz).squeeze())
    dt_true = p_true - min(p_true[0])
    for ix in searchX:
        for iy in searchY:
            ir = np.floor(((ix-r_vector[:,0])**2+(iy-r_vector[:,1])**2)**0.5)
            for iz in searchZ:
                dt = [sim[int(iz)][int(ir[ip]),int(z_t[ip])] for ip in range(p_true.size)]
                dt_sim = dt-min(dt)
                calc1[int(ix),int(iy),int(iz)]=np.linalg.norm(a_factor*(dt_sim-dt_true))
    return calc1
```

Assuming you have a multi-core CPU, you could generate tuples of all possible combinations of `searchX` and `searchY`. Then using a `multiprocessing.Pool` or `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` you could divide the calculations inside the `searchY` loop over all your cores, since they are independant. If you have *n* cores, that should reduce the runtime by approximately a factor of *n*.